# Convert string preceeded with 0 to Json in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, serialization

I'm trying to encode an integer that starts with a 0 into JSON using swift 4.

I'm using a pretty standard JSONSerialization library, but for some reason, after converting the string to data using utf8, I cannot serialize it.

```
let code = "012345" // example code
let body = "{\"code\": " + code + "}"
let stringData = body.data(using: .utf8)!
let jsonArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: stringData, options : .allowFragments) [returns nil]
let data: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonArray as Any, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

Currently, the code breaks on the second to last line (starting with let jsonArray) and returns nil. Note that if I were to change code to "112345", there would be no error. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Replace the `try?` with a `try` in a `do/catch` and in the `catch` add `print(error)`, then you will know the reason for the problem.

Comment: Review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json+Number+with+leading+zero+around+character) on the error you will see.

Comment: wild guess but replace line 2 with `let body = "{\"code\": \"" + code + "\"}"` ? In your code the `body` string is `"{ "code" :  012345 }"`, wouldnt it be preferable to have  `"{ "code" :  "012345" }"` (with quotes) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually creating string, use `Dictionary` and `JSONSerialization` to create `data` as below,

```
let code = "012345"
let body: [String: Any] = ["code": code]
do {
    let stringData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .sortedKeys)
    print(String.init(data: stringData, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Output**

> {"code":"012345"}